# Using Wirt's Leg on another difficulty than it was obtained in?

Tags: diablo-ii

Playing in Nightmare I just picked up [Wirt's Leg](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Wirt%27s_Leg) for the first time. I must have somehow missed it in Normal, so now I'm wondering: will I miss out on anything if I simply bring it back to Normal and use it there instead of playing all the way to Baal and then using it in Nightmare?

(So I just freed Deckard Cain and am still in Act I of Nightmare difficulty.)

Comment: Wirt's leg is universal @_@

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can retrieve [Wirts Leg](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Wirt%27s_Leg) as many times as you like, and use it as many times as you like, in any difficulty without any reprecussions except **ONE**.

If you kill the **[Cow King](http://diablo2.diablowiki.net/Cow_King)** in the [cow level](http://classic.battle.net/diablo2exp/quests/cow.shtml), on any difficulty, you will be unable to open the portal **yourself** to go to the cow level in that difficulty again. You **will** however be able to use **other** player's portals as normal.

Furthermore, if **anyone in your party** kills the Cow King while you are in the cow level, you will no longer be able to open the portal to the cow level on that difficulty.

Comment: Ahh, so the portal between the Cairn Stones will remain accessible then?

Comment: @oKtosiTe yes, the portal to tristam will always be there

Comment: In that case going back to Normal to use my Wirt's Leg seems like a pretty good idea. Will see if I can pick up en extra one there before I attempt going to the cow level. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure but I dont think you can have more than one at any given time. I cant remember clearly.

Comment: No, you can't pick up two of Wirt's legs. If you or anyone in your party has one it won't drop when you loot Wirt's corpse

Comment: Just a slight correction: it should say `if anyone (regardless of if they are in your party or not) has completed Act 5 and kills the Cow King for the first time while you are inside Cow level, then you will no longer be able to open the portal on that difficulty`.

Comment: It should be noted that in D2R killing the CowKing restriction have been dropped. So you can farm without worrying about it